# NodeJS: Require file, execute, remove all

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am encountering a problem.

In my main program, I have multiple functions running.

At one point I just call a random script (file_XXX.js) which can change (several different files). This file is executed and from there my main program calls functions exported from file_XXX and file_XXX calls functions exported from the main program.

There is therefore an exchange of data between the two.

Then at some point when everything is finished, I have to completely delete the import of file_XXX. As if it had never been called (for three reasons, when I call it again I have to start from 0 and to avoid overloading the program as I call other files, and finally, I have setInterval and promise inside this file_XXX so i want to clear all of this).

Thanks for your help!

Currently I am doing this:

- `require("file_XXX.js")`
- Execute function file_XXX.wakeUp()
- data exchange between Main program & this file via exports.function()...
- `delete require.cache[require.resolve("file_XXX.js")];`

But interval and promise keep running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve problems like this is to NOT run any code in the module initialization.  Instead, export functions that you can call when you want to start or stop the action of the module.  Then, you can just call `stop()` to stop whatever was previously in motion (like timers or other module state or other things that need cleaning up) and then when you call `start()` again, it will just start from scratch again.

So, rather than unload the module so you can load it again, just use exported functions to start and stop the action.  Note that nodejs NEVER unloads your actual code anyway so you really don't want to be deleting from the cache and then loading the same module over and over again.  Just load the module ONCE and then use exported functions from the module to accomplish what you want to do.

Note that ESM modules (which you will eventually want to switch to) will never let you unload them or delete from the cache to rerun module initialization.  So, better to just design without doing that.  Just refactor code that is now running at module initialization time into exported functions.

FYI, promises don't "run" (they are just a notification mechanism for monitoring when an asynchronous operation completes).  But, an asynchronous operation that is connected to a promise may be running and you can not stop that by deleting something from the module cache.  That's a completely separate thing.  The only way to stop an asynchronous operation that is in flight is to find or write a cancel operation that is specific to exactly what the asynchronous operation is doing.  Many asynchronous operations in nodejs have no cancel ability.  Others, such as timers do have cancel operations.

Comment: @YogaaD - Since it looks like you're new here, if this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you a few reputation points for following through.